# Store a collection of Mail.MailMessage

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp

I have a WinForm App that sends emails using the awesome [FluentEmail](https://github.com/lukencode/FluentEmail) library by [lukencode](http://lukencode.com/).  Not to get focused on that as what I really need is a way to store `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` so that they can be sent at a later time, when the user has a connection.

This is new ground for me, is this where I should research Object Serialization?  Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question actually, I would say yes, object serialization is definitely what you need, cause as I immagine you want to be able to send mails even if you restart application the day after, so you should guarantee persistency of your data.

Regards